# How to set a hash in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to encrypt the result of this query in variable, the point
is that I am not getting the hash but a strange string of symbols

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EncriptDesEncriptPassword] (
    @pUsuario CHAR(15), 
    @pContraseña AS VARCHAR(10),
)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @ContraseñaHash varchar(70),
    @passwordHash varchar(70);

   SELECT @ContraseñaHash = HASHBYTES ('SHA2_256', @pContraseña) FROM UsersApp2 WHERE Usuario= @pUsuario
```

The expected result:
`0xFEED6896B729BF4A2EA5396FF3EFCB99CEB2187CA825AC8B9598D3819D1142A5`

What I am getting:
`þíh–·)¿J.¥9oóïË™Î²|¨%¬‹•˜ÓB¥`

Comment: Why would you expect a **binary** value to be returned from a `varchar`?

Comment: `HASHBYTES`, as the name implies and the docs explain, produces a `BINARY` type. Stuffing that into a `VARCHAR` without looking is going to get you some mojibake. If you want a hexstring as a string, use [`CONVERT` with the appropriate style](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). But check if you really need this, or if you actually want to store the hash -- in the latter case you may just want to keep it as a `VARBINARY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of varchar you should have used varbinary to get such a result. ie:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EncriptDesEncriptPassword] (
    @pUsuario CHAR(15), 
    @pContraseña AS VARCHAR(10),
     
    
       )
       AS
     BEGIN

        DECLARE
  @ContraseñaHash varbinary(1000),
    @passwordHash varchar(70);

   
   
   SELECT @ContraseñaHash = HASHBYTES ('SHA2_256', @pContraseña)
FROM UsersApp2 
WHERE Usuario= @pUsuario
--...
```